# How to get a filename from a path?

Tags: c#, regex

I need some Regular expression experts for an extra hand. :)

I have different paths,different folders,different amount of folders.

My question:How do I get the last thing - the filename?

For example in the path:

C:\a\b\c\d\e\fgh.ddj

How do I get "fgh.ddj" with regular expressions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need regex's, you can do it just like this, its a system.io helper function:

```
myfilename = Path.GetFileName(mypath);
```

Comment: And if you need more than just the filename then FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(path); Then info contains path, fullname, directoryname and more...

Comment: As do methods on Path: Path.GetDirectoryName, Path.GetFullPath, etc.

Comment: @Vinko: FYI, there are static helper functions for most of that within System.IO.Path, System.IO.File and System.IO.Directory. Most of the time you can write a one-liner instead of using FileInfo.

Comment: he can also use `myfile = mypath.Substring(mypath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);` it does the same job with `Path.GetFileName(mypath);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use FileInfo.  When using FileInfo, it actually doesn't matter if the file is present or not.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\a\b\c\d\e\fgh.ddj");
var fileName = fileInfo.Name;
//this returns "fgh.ddj"
```

If the file is present, of course there's lots of info about file size, last accessed, etc.

Answer (score -4):

If you have perl installed, then you can try something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $fullname = 'C:\a\b\c\d\e\fgh.ddj';
my $file = (split /\\/, $fullname)[-1];
print $file;
```