# Is there any way to get a file name from a path? 

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to get a file name from a path?

For example, how can I get `me.jp` from `c:\MyPic\OldPic\me.jpg`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a filename from a path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942358/how-to-get-a-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may take a look at the [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\MyPic\OldPic\me.jpg");
```