# How to get the stem of a filename from a path?

Tags: c++, regex, filenames, scanf

I want to extract a const char* filename from a const char* filepath. I tried with regex but failed:

```
const char* currentLoadedFile = "D:\files\file.lua";
char fileName[256];
if (sscanf(currentLoadedFile, "%*[^\\]\\%[^.].lua", fileName)) {
return (const char*)fileName; // WILL RETURN "D:\files\file!!
}
```

The issue is that "D:\files\file" will be returned and not the wanted "file"(note: without ".lua")

Comment: [s|f]scanf can't do regex - you have to program it yourself (for example strtok)

Comment: Like dialer said, but also I don't understand your regex. To match the filename would be something like "[\\\\/](.+)$" (very permissive and unsafe on user input).

Comment: find the last backslash (first from the end to beginning), and what is after it is the filename

Comment: This question is a partial dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942358/how-to-get-a-filename-from-a-path). You just need to then lop the .lua extension off the filename to get the stem.

Comment: @razlebe: Tell me how a C# question is remotely a "partial dupe" of a pure C++ question, that doesn't even ask for the same thing and isn't solved the same way.

Comment: @BatchyX - It's the regex element of the question that makes it a partial dupe. NB. *partial*. I'm in no way suggesting there is duplication in the C++ or C# elements of the question - they are completely distinct languages. It's perfectly feasible that both questions could be answered by saying "Use the following regular expression: ....", which would be language-agnostic. The fact that none of the existing *answers* do this doesn't have any bearing on the partial dupe nature of the two *questions*. Does that make my comment clearer?

Comment: @razlebe: Regular expressions only solve one part of the problem. To create the regular expression, you will have to know the directory separator, for instance. And i suppose the method to get the separator is different and unrelated in C# and C++.

Answer (score 15):

Just use [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

std::string filename_noext;
filename_noext = boost::filesystem::path("D:\\files\\file.lua").stem().string().
const char* result_as_const_char = filename_noext.c_str();
```

or alternatively, if you want to introduce bugs yourself :

```
// have fun defining that to the separator of the target OS.
#define PLATFORM_DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR '\\'

// the following code is guaranteed to have bugs.
std::string input = "D:\\files\\file.lua";
std::string::size_type filename_begin = input.find_last_of(PLATFORM_DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR);
if (filename_begin == std::string::npos)
    filename_begin = 0;
else
    filename_begin++;
std::string::size_type filename_length = input.find_last_of('.');
if (filename_length != std::string::npos)
    filename_length = filename_length - filename_begin;

std::string result = input.substr(filename_begin, filename_length);

const char* bugy_result_as_const_char = result.c_str();
```

Comment: Sorry I can only use default C++ functions.

Comment: Why? regex is not part of standard C++ so you will have to use non standard functions. rewriting existing well known good free code is wasting everyone's time. Good programming is making good use of resources

Comment: @luac: boost::filesystem is a planned addition to TR2.

Comment: @luac If you can't use Boost, may I assume this is a homework question? :P

Comment: @Gavin Anderegg :) I just can't add includes to an existing project I am modding

Comment: you can rewrite your `std::string` solution with plain `size_t`, instead of you longwinded typenames. And why would this be buggy? It's not a hard problem to tackle with the STL at hand. (I did not check the code though, but I have similar algorithms written by me and I trust them for what they need to do). No need for big boost-ish dependencies anyway.

Comment: @rubenvb : hint : OS support, path character encoding vs environment character encoding vs internal character encoding. But anyway, the mere fact that you didn't "check the code" mean that you will not be keen on maintaining that mess.

Comment: @rubenv : oh, and i forgot : try that code with "oh/my/god/a/directory/with/a/dot/on.it/mah_file"

Comment: @BatchyX: ok, you found a mistake, which is a logic error that is easy to fix. OS support is a non-issue, as there already is a string containing a path. Encoding shouldn't matter much at the level of directory seperators and periods (at least UTF8 vs other 8-bit encodings).

Comment: @luac What stops you adding includes but allows you to add code - this seems a very artificial restriction. What happens if you need a new class?

Answer (score 15):

What about using std::string?
e.g.

```
  std::string path("d:\\dir\\subdir\\file.ext");
  std::string filename;

  size_t pos = path.find_last_of("\\");
  if(pos != std::string::npos)
    filename.assign(path.begin() + pos + 1, path.end());
  else
    filename = path;
```

Comment: This will yield "file.ext", while the OP wanted to return "file". Also this won't work on UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this portably and easily using the new filesystem library in C++17.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path my_path("D:/files/file.lua");
    std::printf("filename: %s\n", my_path.filename().u8string().c_str());
    std::printf("stem: %s\n", my_path.stem().u8string().c_str());
    std::printf("extension: %s\n", my_path.extension().u8string().c_str());
}
```

Output:

```
filename: file.lua
stem: file
extension: .lua
```

Do note that for the time being you may need to use `#include <experimental/fileystem>` along with `std::experimental::filesystem` instead until standard libraries are fully conforming.

For more documentation on `std::filesystem` check out the [filesystem library reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extract the file:

```
int main()
{
    char pscL_Dir[]="/home/srfuser/kush/folder/kushvendra.txt";
    char pscL_FileName[50];
    char pscL_FilePath[100];
    char *pscL;
    pscL=strrchr(pscL_Dir,'/');
    if(pscL==NULL)
        printf("\n ERROR :INvalid DIr");
    else
    {
        strncpy(pscL_FilePath,pscL_Dir,(pscL-pscL_Dir));
        strcpy(pscL_FileName,pscL+1);
        printf("LENTH [%d}\n pscL_FilePath[%s]\n pscL_FileName[%s]",(pscL-pscL_Dir),pscL_FilePath,pscL_FileName);
    }
    return 0;
}


output: 
LENTH [25}
 pscL_FilePath[/home/srfuser/kush/folder]
 pscL_FileName[kushvendra.txt
```

Comment: Hello Kushvendra, please put your email address in your profile page.

Comment: @kushvendra - here in the comments, or in chat, are the appropriate places to discuss your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1962/) you can find an example. I'm not saying it's the best and I'm sure you could improve on that but it uses only standard C++ (anyway at least what's now considered standard). 
Of course you won't have the features of the boost::filesystem (those functions in the example play along with plain strings and do not guarantee/check you'll actually working with a real filesystem path).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set short name:
char *Filename;
Filename = strrchr(svFilename, '\\');
if ( Filename == NULL )
    Filename = svFilename;

if ( Filename[0] == '\\')
    ++Filename;
if ( !lstrlen(Filename) )
{
    Filename = svFilename;
}
fprintf( m_FileOutput, ";\n; %s\n;\n", Filename );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`_splitpath_s` function to break a path name into its components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx). I don't know if this is standard C or is Windows specific. Anyway this is the function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using std::string;

bool splitPath(string const &path, string &drive, string &directory, string &filename, string &extension) {
    // validate path
    drive.resize(_MAX_DRIVE);
    directory.resize(_MAX_DIR);
    filename.resize(_MAX_FNAME);
    extension.resize(_MAX_EXT);

    errno_t result;
    result = _splitpath_s(path.c_str(), &drive[0], drive.size(), &directory[0], directory.size(), &filename[0], filename.size(), &extension[0], extension.size()); 
    //_splitpath(path.c_str(), &drive[0], &directory[0], &filename[0], &extension[0]); //WindowsXp compatibility
    _get_errno(&result);
    if (result != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        //delete the blank spaces at the end
        drive = drive.c_str();
        directory = directory.c_str();
        filename = filename.c_str();
        extension = extension.c_str();
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is a lot easier and safe to use `std::string` but you could modify this to use `TCHAR*` (`wchar`, `char`)...

For your specific case:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string path = argv[0];
    string drive, directory, filename, extension;
    splitPath(path, drive, directory, filename, extension);
    printf("FILE = %s%s", filename.c_str(), extension.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to **display** a filename to the user on Windows you should respect their shell settings (show/hide extension etc).

You can get a filename in the correct format by calling [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME` flag.