# How can I find the file name in a path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this path:

```
C:\wamp\www\tm\23786.txt
```

I want to get the "23786.txt"

I know we could use explode in php, but how would I do it in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a filename from a path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942358/how-to-get-a-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent to PHP's `explode` would be [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), but you don't need to and shouldn't use it in this case, because there is a specialized method exposed by the framework: [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx). Use it like this:

```
var yourPath = @"C:\wamp\www\tm\23786.txt";
var filename = Path.GetFileName(yourPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, in C# land we don't like when stuff explodes, so we have

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `Path.GetFileName(@"C:\wamp\www\tm\23786.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [`Path class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) method [`GetFileName(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx), such as:

```
var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

You can also just omit the `System.IO` qualification if you have a `using System.IO`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\wamp\www\tm\23786.txt");
```